# c++ object model disadvantage. What is the solution?

Tags: c++

I m in learning  phase of c++. While reading inside the c++ Object model, i understood the
the different object models.

1) Simple Object Model.

2) Table driven object model.

3) c++ Object model.

**Question:**

"*Its primary drawback is the need to recompile unmodified code that makes use of an object of a class for which there has been an addition, removal, or modification of the nonstatic class data members.*"

I understood the above statement. Any changes that happens in the class definition, then 
the source code that uses the same class needs to be recompiled.

that means, there is some why to achieve the same without recompilation also. How to do that?  If someone provides the sample code that would be great. I am using g++ in Linux/Ubuntu.

Comment: Your question is not clear, but you may be looking for the [pimpl idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill04.htm).

Answer (score 6):

Typical idiom to prevent recompilation while modifying class is PImpl.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer#C.2B.2B

Answer (score 1):

There might be ways to achieve the same in other languages/object models, but not in C++. Otherwise that would not be a drawback of the C++ object model.

It is however possible to mitigate the consequences, e.g. by (1) exporting only interfaces a.k.a. pure abstract classes from libraries and (2) never changing published interfaces. If a new API must be added, export it via a new interface (even if it refers to an old/modified implementation class).

I'm not sure code samples would help that much. This is not a coding technique. If you know what is a pure abstract class, you are all set.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that exposing the implementation details in the header can have advantages, as well as the disadvantage of forcing recompilation when the details change; functions can be more easily inlined, which can improve runtime performance. You will need to decide where and when that trade-off is worth the cost.

It is possible to hide all the private implementation details inside a source file by introducing an extra level of indirection. One common approach is the pointer-to-private-implementation (or "pimpl") idiom, for example:

```
// Header file
class Thing {
public:
    Thing(...);
    ~Thing();

    // Public interface

private:
    struct Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> impl;
};

// Source file
struct Thing::Impl {
    // private details
};

Thing(...) : impl(new Impl(...)) {}
~Thing() {}

// Implementation of public interface
```

Another possibility is to define an abstract interface, with one or more factories to create concrete instances containing the implementation, for example:

```
// Header file
class Thing {
public:
    virtual ~Thing() {}

    static std::unique_ptr<Thing> make(...);

    // Pure virtual public interface
};

// Source file
class ThingImpl : public Thing {
    // Implementation of public interface

    // Private implementation details
};

std::unique_ptr<Thing> Thing::make(...) {
    return std::unique_ptr<Thing>(new ThingImpl(...));
}
```

Both of these approaches place all the implementation details inside a source file, so that is the only thing that needs recompiling when the details change. But both introduce extra pointer indirections and/or indirect function calls, which could impact runtime performance.